# Qt qml shows error when I use static build

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I built static Qt 5.9.6 and built my app with this Qt version. But I get errors in qml:

```
QtQml 2.3: QML module does not contain 
informationn about components 
contained in plugins
Qt.labs.platform 1.0: QML module not 
found
QtQuick.Controls 2.2: is not installed
QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3: not found
```

For example, there is QtQuick.Controls 1.4, or Quick 2.9 also is here.

Here's my script for building:

`./configure -static -prefix /usr/lib/qt5.9.6-amd64/qt5 -opensource -confirm-license -nomake tests -nomake examples -no-openssl -qt-doubleconversion -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-pcre -qt-xcb -qt-harfbuzz -qt-zlib -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtqa -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtrepotools -skip qtscript -skip qtscxml -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtserialport -skip qtspeech -skip qttranslations -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwebview`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error and when i inspected it further, i found that directX should be disabled using the following flag in the config

```
-no-feature-d3d12
```